# is 丁度 only a suffix?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

三時ちょうどで = at 3 o'clock sharp
百円ちょうどだ = its exactly 100 yen

I get this sort of usage for 丁度、but if I want to refer to the **exactness** of something, how would I do that?

eg.
丁度じゃなくてもいいですよ Its fine if its not exact (in reference to anything really, for example, cooking and ingredient amounts)

丁度同じです its the exact same

丁度正しいですか is that exactly right? (maybe this sentence is a bit weird...)

Comment: The last one is quite weird, the others seem fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question itself, no it's not only a suffix. You could just as easily state your first two examples as ちょうど三時で or ちょうど百円だ.

And as per your intuition and @stack reader's comment, the last one is somewhat weird. What, exactly, is weird about it is more difficult to explain, and I don't have a good reference on hand. I suspect it's a mostly a matter of differences in collocations between languages. The Goldilocks "just right" is 「ちょうどいい」, and the  perfectly correct "exactly right" would likely be expressed as 「100%正しい」or「完全に正しい」, for example.

Interestingly, if you have a noun following 正しい, you can find expressions like 「ちょうど正しい長さ」or「ちょうど正しい位置」, so it works if you specify what, specifically, is "just/exactly right".